# kdevelop project and source folder

Tags: project, kdevelop4

Is there a way to change the project files of a Kdevelop to another folder (outside the source files)?

Like in Netbeans for example :

**project folder** : /home/xxx/KdevelopProjects/MyProject

**source folder** : /home/xxx/workspace/MyProject

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. KDevelop4 creates a hidden dir .kdev4 in project's dir which contains all data. Why do you want to move it?

Comment: I don't want those files t be versionned with Git. I know i can pt them in .gitignore file but before that I just wanted to know if its possible to change their location. Thanks anyway

Comment: I see. I just gitignore them